# Eclipse's Java Compiler produces different stack traces when run from the command line

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

A little know feature of the Eclipse's Java compiler is that you can [run it from the command line](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm).

This works well (after patching plexus-compiler to use the latest release).

My problem: The stack traces are different when I compile the code from the command line. For example, when I run the compiler in the IDE, I get this output:

```
     at com.some.Foo.method(Foo.java:312)
```

but when I compile the code from the command line, I get this:

```
     at com.some.Foo.method(com.some.Foo:312)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What's going here???

Analyzing the class files with `javap` gives:

```
SourceFile: "Foo.java"
```

and

```
SourceFile: "com.some.Foo"
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Perhaps you have a wonky $CLASSPATH set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a patched `plexus-compiler-eclipse` (I patched the POM to include the 3.7/Helios compiler).

In the class `EclipseJavaCompiler.CompilationUnit`, there is this code:

```
    public char[] getFileName()
    {
        return className.toCharArray();
    }
```

which should be

```
    public char[] getFileName()
    {
        return sourceFile.toCharArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat baz/Bar.java
class Foo {
}

$ java -jar eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.8.0.v_C19.jar baz/Bar.java

$ javap -c baz/Foo.class
Compiled from "Bar.java"
...
```

That's Funny, It Works On My Machine?

Win7, Java 7, Eclipse 3.8.0 (identifies itself as Indigo, 20110615-0604).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed in plexus-compiler-eclipse version 1.9.1 (or maybe some other version between 1.9.1 and 1.7)